# VBA EXCEL MACRO - changing cell values while looping through target.cells

Tags: excel, vba

CONTEXT :

I've been working creating a schedule on Excel and I want to make make a few things more simple for the user while they are adding information.

Each day is separated into day and night ("jour" and "nuit" in French : so I use "J" and "N" as identifiers)

I'm currently creating a macro that executes when one OR MORE cell(s) is changed  in a certain range (i.e. one of the cells in the schedule). If certain String codes are typed and committed in a cell I want those codes to be formatted uniformly: the codes in uppercase followed by a lowercase "j" or "n" depending on wether it was typed in a column that is day or night.
(The codes are predefined but I don't want to use a dropdown list of the different codes)

Example : if a user types "r" in a day column, the cell value should change to "Rj".

If the user types "rj", "rn", "RJ", ... it should still return "Rj".

So, if the user already has an "Rj" cell and drags the value the the right it should alternate "Rj" and "Rn"

exception : if user types "x" it should just return an uppercase "X"

PROBLEM :

I make a for each loop that loops through the targeted cells (can be one or more cells if the user drags the data to adjacent columns or rows).
However, even if there is only one cell, it seems as though the loop is happening multiple times and it's really slowing down the process of changing cell data.

I've tried using both if statements and select case to see if it made a difference in efficiency - select case is a little faster (even though it's quite a lot longer) but it's still takes ages.

I wondered whether it was my computer but it's a recent and quite powerful machine - all other programming runs just fine.

Also, even if the a case condition is met, the Case Else still seems to be executed...

I found that by adding a space in the case strings helps speed up the process because if a cell goes through the for each multiple times, as it's been assigned a value with not spaces it won't correspond to the different cases.

You'll notice at the end of my code that there are some codes that can't be on a weekend or during the night (commented in the select case because of the Case Else problem). It doesn't matter to me if those take a little longer to execute but I don't want it to slow down the other options.

Here's what the schedule looks like :

[night/day schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLnDg.png)

and here are the two versions of my vba code :

```
    Select Case :
```

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    'On Error GoTo done
    ' La variable KeyCells determine les cellules qui detectent le changement
    Set KeyCells = Range("T41:KC66")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
    Dim valeur As String
    For Each cell In Target
        valeur = UCase(cell.Value) & " "
        Select Case valeur
            Case "R "
                If ActiveSheet.Cells(40, cell.Column) = "J" Then
                    cell.Value = "Rj"
                Else
                    cell.Value = "Rn"
                End If
            Case "Q "
                If ActiveSheet.Cells(40, cell.Column) = "J" Then
                    cell.Value = "Qj"
                Else
                    cell.Value = "Qn"
                End If
            Case "SC1 "
                If ActiveSheet.Cells(40, cell.Column) = "J" Then
                    cell.Value = "SC1j"
                Else
                    cell.Value = "SC1n"
                End If
            Case "SC2 "
                If ActiveSheet.Cells(40, cell.Column) = "J" Then
                    cell.Value = "SC2j"
                Else
                    cell.Value = "SC2n"
                End If
            Case "MAO "
                If ActiveSheet.Cells(40, cell.Column) = "J" Then
                    cell.Value = "MAOj"
                Else
                    cell.Value = "MAOn"
                End If
            Case "MUC "
                If ActiveSheet.Cells(40, cell.Column) = "J" Then
                    cell.Value = "MUCj"
                Else
                    cell.Value = "MUCn"
                End If
            Case "UHC "
                If ActiveSheet.Cells(40, cell.Column) = "J" Then
                    cell.Value = "UHCj"
                Else
                    cell.Value = "UHCn"
                End If
            Case "U "
                If ActiveSheet.Cells(40, cell.Column) = "J" Then
                    cell.Value = "Uj"
                Else
                    cell.Value = "Un"
                End If
            Case "S "
                If ActiveSheet.Cells(40, cell.Column) = "J" Then
                    cell.Value = "Sj"
                Else
                    cell.Value = "Sn"
                End If
            Case "X "
                cell.Value = "X"

            'Case Else
                'MsgBox "hello"
                'if not cell.value = "R" or cell.
                'If valeur = "CA" Or valeur = "CM" Or valeur = "CLM" Or valeur = "CMD" Or valeur = "CET" Or valeur = "CF" Or valeur = "CP" Or valeur = "CG" Or valeur = "RTT" Or valeur = "ASA" Or valeur = "JR" Then
                   ' If ActiveSheet.Cells(37, cell.Column) = "sam" Or ActiveSheet.Cells(37, cell.Column) = "dim" Or ActiveSheet.Cells(40, cell.Column) = "N" Then
                    '    cell.Value = ""
                    'Else
                    '    cell.Value = valeur
                  '  End If
             '   ElseIf Left(valeur, 1) = "H" Then
              '      cell.Value = valeur
              '  End If
            End Select
    Next cell
End If

done:
End Sub
```

I removed extra cases such as Case "RJ " or "RN " for example because it was slow but to do want i need, they need to be included (and because it's very repetitive and you don't need to see all the cases).
I also tried changing the syntax like this and adding a GoTo to avoid redundancy in the code (but didn't help) :

```
Case "R ", "RJ ", "RN "
```

```
    If statements (seems much better but is much slower...):
```

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    'On Error GoTo done
' La variable KeyCells d_termine les cellules modifiables
    Set KeyCells = Range("T41:KC66")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target.Cells) Is Nothing Then
    'on parcourt toutes les cellules modifiées
    For Each cell In Target.Cells
    
        'si l'utilisatur entre une valeur de service valable et précise j ou n
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value, Range("C73:C90"), 0)) Then
            'on s'assure que j ou n soit saisie correctement
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(40, cell.Column) = "J" Then
                service = UCase(Left(cell.Value, Len(cell.Value) - 1)) & "j"
                cell.Value = service
            Else
                service = UCase(Left(cell.Value, Len(cell.Value) - 1)) & "n"
                cell.Value = service
            End If
        
        'idem mais l'utilisateur n'a pas précisé le jour ou la nuit
        ElseIf Not IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value, Range("B73:B81"), 0)) Then
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(40, cell.Column) = "J" Then
                cell.Value = UCase(cell.Value) & "j"
            Else
                cell.Value = UCase(cell.Value) & "n"
            End If
        
        'si l'entrée correspond à un congé
        ElseIf Not IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value, Range("D73:D83"), 0)) Then
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(37, cell.Column) = "sam" Or ActiveSheet.Cells(37, cell.Column) = "dim" Or ActiveSheet.Cells(40, cell.Column) = "N" Then
                cell.Value = ""
            Else:
                cell.Value = UCase(cell.Value)
            End If

        End If
    Next cell
End If
done:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Here are the cells i use for the codes in the second example

[cells with codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LFra.png)

Any help at all is appreciated. I hope this isn't too much information, I didn't want to miss anything out!

Answer (score 0):

When you update a sheet from an event handler, that will again trigger the event, and this can lead to endless loops or at least problems with execution speed. If you're going to update the sheet in the monitored area, use `Application.EnableEvents = False`, make the change(s), then set it back to `True` (you *must* do this or your code will stop responding).

Very lightly tested:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, jn As String, v, rngList As Range, m

    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Me.Range("T41:KC66"), Target)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    
        On Error GoTo haveError
        Set rngList = Me.Range("C73:C90") 'list of codes to match on
        
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each cell In rng.Cells
        
            v = UCase(Trim(cell.Value)) 'upper-case
            
            If Len(v) > 0 Then          'something was entered
                If Right(v, 1) = "J" Or Right(v, 1) = "N" Then
                    v = Left(v, Len(v) - 1) 'remove any trailing J or N
                End If
                
                If Len(v) > 0 Then
                    m = Application.Match(v, rngList, 0) 'in list? (case-insensitive)
                    If Not IsError(m) Then
                        jn = Me.Cells(40, cell.Column).Value           'day/night
                        cell.Value = rngList.Cells(m).Value & LCase(jn) 'matches case to list
                    Else
                        'what to do if no match?
                    End If
                Else
                    'what if user just enters j or n ?
                End If
            End If 'anything was entered
        
        Next cell
    End If

haveError:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was really helpful! I had to change a couple of things for it to work perfectly but now it's doing exactly what I wanted to